# Best way to represent HTML part when writing a complex jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a complex jQuery plugin to write, It does have a lot of html to show on screen and I am supposed to create them. Well, what is the best way to do the job. I can already hard code them for sure , but is there any other elegant method? is there a way to use some kind of templating?. definitely I don't want to have lot more dependency either.

Comment: any link to your plugin? what kind of work you need to do. put some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them in an external file(s) and load them when you need but this means plugin users will have to download all your files, instead of a single js file. Another option I used before (not for a plugin though) is to have an object inside your plugin which holds all the html you want. This makes it easier to write the plugin as the html doesn't clutter the plugin code. Also when you need to edit the html, it's in a single place. You can also put your templating code inside this object.

```
var pi = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.getNewDiv = function(){
        return repo.getDiv();
    }

    //..... all your plug in code goes here and at the bottom

    var htmlRepository = function() {
        var divCode = "<div></div>";

        this.getDiv = function(){
           return divCode;
        };

        this.getSpan = function(){
            return "Span Content";
        }

        this.getDivWithSpan = function(){
            return getSpan().wrap(divCode); //etc
        }
    };

    var repo = new htmlRepository();
}
```

Comment: Thats a good idea to keep everything at a single place .. thanks :)

Comment: @jossie I don't know the nature of your plugin but come to think of it some plugins require you to download their css files as well. If you use an external html file to get your html from, users could download that and add their own css classes, modify the html content to match their needs, etc.